My Caesar Cipher code is failing when I pass in a string containing uppercase characters
I wrote a Caesar Cipher encryption program in Ruby. It seemingly worked just fine when I passed in strings containing lowercase characters until I passed in a string that had an uppercase character. The code is raising a NoMethodError in between the lines of main.rb:7:in block in `caeser_cipher': undefined method `+' for nil (NoMethodError) whenever I pass in a string that has uppercase characters.
Here's my code:
def caeser_cipher(string, key)
  alphabet = ('a'..'z').to_a
  cipher = ""

  string.each_char do |char|
    if alphabet.include?(char.downcase) 
      new_key = (alphabet.index(char) + key) % 26
      char = alphabet[new_key]
    end 
    cipher << char
  end
  cipher
end

puts "Enter whatever you please (of course a string of text) that you want encrypted!!!"
text = gets.chomp
puts "And then the offset value"
num = gets.chomp.to_i

puts caeser_cipher(text, num)

I tried wrapping char = alphabet[new_key] in another if condition to check for char == char.upcase and if that evaluated to true, to do this char = alphabet[new_key].upcase which also failed.

char = alphabet[new_key] is not the cause. The exception occurs on the line before: alphabet.index(char) returns nil for an uppercase char which results in nil + key.

Omg I read the exception so many times and I still missed that. Will it work if I did alphabet.index(char.downcase)?

Yes, but the char from alphabet[new_key] will always be lowercase. You could upcase it depending on whether char is an uppercase letter. You could also use two separate alphabets. Or a hash which maps each letter to its encoded counterpart. Lots of options here. BTW, the 7 in main.rb:7 refers to the line number ;)

Thanks a lot. I wrapped it around if/else conditionals to see if char is uppercase, if it is, it shovels alphabet[new_key].upcase into char and otherwise leave it as it is and it's working as expected.

The problem is on line
new_key = (alphabet.index(char) + key) % 26

If the char is not an lowercase character, it will not be found in the alphabet, so index will return nil.
You need to look up the lowercased version of the char, so maybe change the line to
new_key = (alphabet.index(char.downcase) + key) % 26



Thanks a lot. That was so silly of me to not have noticed that even though I read through the exception so many times but it's now working exactly as I intended it to.
